# Some trouble with passing a list of values from a HTML form into a C# method

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, razor

I am generating a number of checkboxes from a database and rendering them in my HTML. The functionality I would like is for the user to be able to select a number of the checkboxes, the userID of this user to be passed into a C# method which will run an algorithm and render another page. How can I pass this data to my algorithm effectively?

Here is my code so far :

```
@{  
    var db = Database.Open("mPlan");
    var sql = "SELECT * from Users";
    var result = db.Query(sql);
 }
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
    @{foreach (var user in result) {
    <label for="username">@user.Username</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="@user" id="username" />
    }
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="userId" value="@user.UserId" />
```

The form should then pass the values for userId as a comma-seperated list.

---

To retrieve the list of ids you could do the following:

```
string userIds = Request.Form["userId"]; // get from http post as comma-separated list
string [] arrUserIds;                    // string array to hold ids
if (userIds != null)                     // if the userIds isn't null, split into the array
    arrUserIds = userIds.Split(',');
```

Comment: And how can I retrieve the values in the next file? I know in PHP it would be $_GET['userID'], do you happen to know what the same construct would be in c# ? If I wanted to have a List<String> of UserIds for instance?

Comment: var userIds = Request.Form["userId"]; See edited answer above.